# How to extract the adjusted r squared from uGARCHfit class data?

Tags: r, r-squared, garch

I would like to see how good my independent variables describe the variations of my dependent variable. I have fitted an ARX-GARCHX-model, so my fit is of class `uGARCHfit`. Is there anyway to get the (adjusted) $R^2$ out of it (with one command)?

Comment: Under conditional heteroskedasticity, it could make sense to weight the observations inversely by the estimated standard deviations of shocks when calculating the $R^2$.

Comment: On a second thought, Jeffrey Wooldridge does not agree with me [here](https://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1383469-robust-standard-errors-and-goodness-of-fit-measures): *There is nothing wrong with R-squared as a goodness-of-fit measure when there is heteroskedasticity. I explain this in Chapter 8 of my introductory econometrics book. The R-squared has to do with unconditional variances, while heteroskedasticity is most properly viewed as nonconstant conditional variances.*

Comment: And after some more thinking... Including weights in the calculation of $R^2$ could be justified if different data points had different probabilities to be drawn from the population. That is, weighting could be used to correct for the sample not being representative (oversampling of some points, undersampling of other). But the data points of a GARCH process are all equally representative, and so the logic of correcting for an unrepresentative sample does not apply. Hence, simple $R^2$ (adjusted or not) should do.

Comment: In my case I have just one sample (one population). Weighting would not make sense.

Comment: I don't understand the argumentation of Jeffrey Wooldridge. For me it sounds contradicting. First he says you can use R-squared  when there is heteroskedasticity and then he says that R-squared should be used when there is an unconditional variance.

Comment: @RichardHardy do you also know the coding for it? Assuming that x is the fitted model of class uGARCHfit. I am looking for something similar to summary(x)$r.squared (which is used for lm-models).

Comment: No, I do not know the code. Also, I do not understand your comment on one sample (one population) as an argument against weighting. That sample can either be representative or not, and hence my comment on an unrepresentative sample applies there perfectly.

Comment: Otherwise I would just do it in the complicated way:
`1 - (sum(x@fit$residuals^2) / sum((y-mean(y))^2))`

where x is the fitted model and y the dependent variable.

Comment: That does not look *too* difficult. But it is your call.

Comment: @RichardHardy but how can I know if the data is representativ or not if it is the only one I have? How can I weight on something when the sample is the only thing that gives me an idea about the data?

Comment: In time series data, typically the points are equally representative since they all belong to the same particular trajectory (the same realization of the time series process). Basically, you can disregard *all* of my comments in your case. I posted the first one without having thought long enough, but the point with the rest of them was to explain and elaborate on the issue more generally.